# jQuery getting selected option of dynamically rendered dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I am working on an MVC + jQuery project, I am creating dropdown list on runtime. After rendering while submitting form through jQuery, I am trying to get selected value. Drop down is rendered and working fine

[image]

Also I can check in source code. I am trying to get dropdown list by

```
 $('#Monday_Periods').children('.PeriodRow').each(function () {

    var elements = $(this).html();
    var found = $('.Subject', elements);           

});
```

I found all objects in variable `found`, and I can see it in Chrome debug

[image]

But after this I am unable to get selected value. As you can see in debug mode that no option is selected. I tried to get by `val` or `text` but no luck. Anybody can tell me that how I can get selected value

Answer (score 1):

`$(this).html();` is loosing the reference to the DOM (`html()` returns a String, not a DOM node).

Try to modify in:

```
var elements = $(this);
var found = $('.Subject', elements);
found.each(function(el){
   console.log($(this).val());
}
```

or use directly (you already have an id on it!):

```
$('#subject1').val();
```

---

#### EDIT: SNIPPET ADDED

```js
function printResults(){
  $('#Monday_Periods').children('.PeriodRow').each(function () {

      var elements = $(this);
      var found = $('.Subject', elements);
      found.each(function(el){
         console.log($(this).val());
      });           
    
  });
}

$('#print-results').click(printResults);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form id="Monday_Periods">
  <div class="PeriodRow">
    <select class="Subject">
      <option value="none">-- Select Subject --</option>
      <option value="1">Biology</option>
      <option value="2">Physics</option>
    </select>
    
    <select class="Subject">
      <option value="none">-- Select Subject --</option>
      <option value="1">Biology</option>
      <option value="2">Physics</option>
    </select>

  </div>
  <button type="button" id="print-results">PRINT RESULTS</button> 
</form>
```

Comment: the html string returned from html() should contain the selected property when called after an option was selected... but nice answer!

Comment: @sjkm You are surely right if you talk about attributes on HTML tags... But the value is a property of the DOM node (so not -always- written on the tag, accessible with Js and in Form submissions

Comment: Thanks @squaleLis. I can get value by $('#subject1').val(); but the problem is this is an array with name subject1,subject2,subject3 ..... that is why i am trying to iterate each control by class ".Subject". When tried other option $(this) , it is returning same html string with no option selected

Comment: @squaleLis in console it prints "none". I agree to your statement that actually we are loosing context to DOM.I think "$('.Subject', elements);"  is misleading me i should try some other approach

Comment: I added a snippet... and it works! maybe you can find some difference between this and your code ;)